# What is typical v.surf.xxx execution time?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, interpolation, performance

What is the typical v.surf.xxx exicution time?

I am trying to run v.surf.bspline on a set of ~1600 points.  It has bee running for about an hour now and is stuck at spot indicated in the image.  [image: this is where it gets stuck]

I am wondering about the time because I am not sure which interpolation method I will use and want to see the results fom all of the diferent methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use GRASS GIS from QGIS, you need to understand the commands of GRASS

[v.surf.bspline](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.surf.bspline.html) uses a Bicubic or bilinear spline interpolation algorithm with Tykhonov regularization. As with all the GRASS GIS commands, It has many options that it is important to understand before applying the algorithm (GRASS GIS is not QGIS):

[image]

and different results depending on these options:

[image]

So there is no typical execution time. That depends precisely on the options you can choose.

Comment: So after looking at the documentation and your post i think i have a better understanding of what is going on.  But is the "10 x 10", "25 x 25", and "50 x 50" are the east-west and north-south spline steps?

Comment: Yes, but you can also modify the Tychonov parameters (look at the examples in [GRASS GIS pas à pas pour les débutants: 10- les modules d'interpolation spatiale: splines régularisées avec tension (RST) et splines bilinéaires et bicubiques avec régularisation de Tykhonov](http://www.portailsig.org/content/grass-gis-pas-pas-pour-les-debutants-10-les-modules-d-interpolation-spatiale-splines-regular)), in French, but the screen captures are universal...

Comment: @gene: nice screenshots! It would be great to have them for the manual page of v.surf.bspline, ideally based on the North Carolina dataset...